# Array_Merge for JSON output

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am combining two arrays then encoding into JSON for output.  I get a funky value in JSON output at the start of the second array.  This is the `"0":` item.  I can't figure out where this is coming from.

Combine the arrays and output json:

```
$combine = array_merge(array('array1'=>$bay_events, array('array2'=>$key_events)));
$finish = json_encode($combine);

$callback = $_GET['callback'];
echo $callback.$finish;
```

JSON output:

```
{
    "array1": [
        {
            "event_id": "3914",
            "event_name": "Test"
        }
    ],
    "0": {  <--- this should not be here
        "array2": [
            {
                "event_id": "3913",
                "event_name": "Testssdgs This Is how"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I cant figure out where `"0":` is coming from. Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using `array_merge` the proper way

**The problem**

- You where trying to **merge only one array**
- The **second element** in the only array refers to another array wich resulted in another index `0`

Explanation

```
$combine = array_merge(array('array1'=>$bay_events, array('array2'=>$key_events)))
                         ^      ^                    ^
                         |      |                    |       
      Only One array ----+  Fist Index           Second Index Another array
```

This is the **proper way** to use `array_merge`

```
$combine = array_merge(array('array1'=>$bay_events), array('array2'=>$key_events));
```

Or Just **remove it totally**

```
$combine = array('array1'=>$bay_events, 'array2'=>$key_events);
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because of this line

```
$combine = array_merge(array('array1'=>$bay_events, array('array2'=>$key_events)));
```

try like this

```
$combine = array_merge(array('array1'=>$bay_events, 'array2'=>$key_events));
```

just tested according to your data, here it is

```
$bay_events = array('event_id' => '3914', 'event_name' => 'Test'); 
$key_events = array('event_id' => '3913', 'event_name' => 'Testssdgs This Is how');
$combine = array_merge(array('array1'=>$bay_events, 'array2'=>$key_events));
echo json_encode($combine);die;


{
"array1":{"event_id":"3914","event_name":"Test"},
"array2":{"event_id":"3913","event_name":"Testssdgs This Is how"}
}
```

Comment: You should not use array_merge with only one array; no need for that. See @Baba answer...

Comment: @Glavić according to [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php), array_merge() Merges the `elements` of `one` or more arrays together, so it is also acceptable

Comment: I did not wrote that this is invalid code or that is will not work, I just said it has no meaning... Only difference is, when running array_merge() on single array, the array will have reorganized numeric keys...